# Giving the user the option to loop a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, do-while

I'm having trouble giving the user an option to loop a loop.  This program works fine

```all
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    // goal is to calculate the sum of the first 10 terms of Leibniz's Series....
    // calculated by 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ..... - 1/19

    int termNumber;  // keeps track of term numbers
    int numberOfTerms = 0;

    cout << "Enter number of Terms";
    cin >> numberOfTerms;


    double sum = 0.0;
    int sign = +1;

    for (termNumber = 1; termNumber <= numberOfTerms; termNumber++)
        {
        sum += ( sign / (2.0 * termNumber - 1));
        sign *= -1;
        }

    cout << "\n\n The sum is " << ( 4 * sum) << "\n\n";


    } // end body of loop
```

I need to give the user an option to repeat the program if he would like so I thought I could put it in a do-while loop, but when I do that it only loops  "enter number of terms"  any way I try to format it.  This is the best I have at the moment.

```all
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

// goal is to calculate the sum of the first 10 terms of Leibniz's Series....
// calculated by 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ..... - 1/19

cout << "\nGiven a positive integer specifying some number of terms, this program\n approximates "
    "pi using Leibniz' Formula and the given number of terms.\n\n" ;
cout << "Leibniz' formula is 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + ... = Pi / 4.\n\n";

char yes = 0;
double sum = 0.0;

do {
    int termNumber;  // keeps track of term numbers
    int numberOfTerms = 0;


    int sign = +1;
    cout << "enter number of terms.\n";
    cin >> numberOfTerms;

    for (termNumber = 1; termNumber <= numberOfTerms; termNumber++)
        {
        sum += (sign / (2.0 * termNumber - 1));
        sign *= -1;
        }

    } 
    while (yes = 1);
cout << "\n\n The sum is " << (4 * sum) << "\n\n";
cout << "would you like to go again? " << yes;

} // end body of loop
```

I would like to give them the option to try a different amount using term numbers where y/Y and n/N  work.

Thanks for any help I may get.

Comment: Nearly right, you just have to move the `cout` lines up above the `while(yes = 1);`, change the `yes=1` from an assignment to a comparison, and use `cin` to read the "Would you like to continue" answer. (using a `char`, you'd probably also have to compare with `'Y' or 'y'` instead of 1)

Comment: A good compiler warns if you do this: `while (yes = 1);`. An even better compiler may then also warn that the condition `yes==1` is never satisfied ...

Comment: Putting the cout lines above while creates an error on the cout's  "expected a while"

Answer (score 2):

You need a `cin` to set yes and your `cout` lines are in the wrong place. They need to be inside of your do while loop. And an `==` in your while

```
do {
int termNumber;  // keeps track of term numbers
int numberOfTerms = 0;


int sign = +1;
cout << "enter number of terms.\n";
cin >> numberOfTerms;

for (termNumber = 1; termNumber <= numberOfTerms; termNumber++)
    {
    sum += (sign / (2.0 * termNumber - 1));
    sign *= -1;
    }
cout << "\n\n The sum is " << (4 * sum) << "\n\n";
cout << "would you like to go again? " << yes;
cin >> yes
} 
while (yes == 1);
```

try that

Comment: yeah I just caught that. I'm being a bit hasty it's towards the end of the work day and my build just finished -.-

Comment: This is getting me closer.  Thank you, I'll see where I can get.

Comment: Just to be nitpicky: you should keep variable declaration outside of loops. It doesn't always matter, but it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you learned to use

```
continue;
```

in a for loop? I think this fits your description, basically what

```
continue;
```

does is it returns to the beginning of the for-loop in this case in a certain scenario.

Comment: Why would that be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents but maybe you can combine both of your ideas and use functions. Put the code you have in the do part above into a function with a parameter of number of terms. Also use your for loop in the body of this function. Then on the outside of your for loop call another function that asks the user if they would like to continue and also ask a new number for the "terms" and pass that back into the first function if the user supplies a 'y' or 'Y' else if a 'n' or 'N' you can just stop the program

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `do while` loop is that the variable used in the `while()` statement must have been defined outside of the loop body, even though syntactically is belongs to the loop. This can be avoided when using a `for` loop instead, which allows the definition of such variables within the `for` statement. Here is an example.

```
inline double leibniz (int n) noexcept   // function for Leibniz sum
{
  double result=0;
  for(int k=1,sign=1; n; --n,++++k,sign=-sign)
    result += double(sign)/double(k);
  return result;
};

int main()
{
                                      // no loose variables defined outside loop
  for(bool again=true; again; ) {     // control variable only lives withing loop body
    int n;                            // number of terms, only needed within loop body
    std::cout<<"number of terms = ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout<<"result = "<<leibniz(n)<<'\n'
             <<"try again? (1/0)";
    std::cin >>again;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I didn't know the `continue;` yet, but I learned about it.

The major problem was my `cin` and `cout` were not in the right spot like stated before. Redid the last line to `while (yes == 'Y' || yes == 'y');`   and now all works perfectly.

You guys are great!